# Create a third array of identical key-value pairs found in two separate arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

If I have two associative arrays with equal numbers of key-value pairs, is there a streamlined way to create a 3rd array that gives the key-value pairs that are present in both. It has to be identical key-value pairs, not just identical keys or identical values (array_intersect identifies identical keys only). cheers

Comment: Are you sure that the fact that the two arrays have an equal number of key/value pairs is a necessary condition for what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is a relatively easy problem to solve. What do you mean by 'streamlined'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array3 = array_intersect_assoc($array1, $array2);
```

Check out the PHP Manual for [array_intersect_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) which explains: array_intersect_assoc() returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that the keys are used in the comparison unlike in array_intersect().

Comment: @AD7six: I don't understand the interest of copying the official documentation here instead of posting a link to it.

Comment: Why put a link in the answer? A quick Google of `array_intersect_assoc` brings you directly to the PHP manual.

Comment: I appreciate the response, and as I'm new to PHP this kind of direct response is good. Cheers

Comment: LMAO! I've never dealt with so many overconfident zealots in my entire life! Thank G-d this site has real technical value. I guess I have always been a proponent of making an answer to a question more valuable by giving the asker a reason to go learn something on their own.

Comment: Fair enough - reverted and vote given to the much later answer which does link to the docs. Providing an answer should not result in using google to get to relevant information - it's a Q&A site; not a Q&?+Google site.

Answer (score 1):

if `$a` and `$b` are your arrays, you can get the third array, `$c` like this:

```
$c = array_intersect_assoc($a, $b);
```

I used the native [array_intersect_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) function;

Answer (score 0):

I know how to get keys in both array and values in both arrays, but not an intersection of keys and values. However, it isn't complicated. Assume you have array $a and $b and want to make array $c:

```
$c = array();
foreach($a as $k=>$v) if($b[$k] == $v) $c[$k]=$v;
```

That will throw errors if $b[$k] is not set, but you can ignore those if you like.

Comment: If you add an `isset($b[$k])` inside of your `if` condition, it will get rid of the `will throw errors` problem you mention in your last statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would merge both arrays then remove duplicates for simplicity

Merge both arrays:

```
    function merge_common_keys(){
    $arr = func_get_args();
    $num = func_num_args();

    $keys = array();
    $i = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<$num;++$i){
        $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($arr[$i]));
    }
    $keys = array_unique($keys);

    $merged = array();

    foreach($keys as $key){
        $merged[$key] = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$num;++$i){
            $merged[$key][] = isset($arr[$i][$key])?$arr[$i][$key]:null;
        }
    }
    return $merged;
}
```

Merge then remove duplicates

```
$merged = merge_common_keys($array1,$array2);    

$unique = array_unique($merged );
```

Comment: You can't have common key/value with a merge.